# SQL Group by Intervals of 2 power n

Tags: sql

I need to aggregate some rows in a huge database and need to group them based on 2 power n.
Ex: I first need to aggregate 1 row, then 2 rows, then 4 rows etc.

Can anyone help me how to use group by in this case?

Thanks

Comment: ?  I think you need to give an example of what's in your database and what output you want...they way this is worded suggests you need to read up on what an aggregate / group by is.  When you say aggregate 1 row, then 2, then 4 etc...are you asking for 1 row returned, then 2, then 4?  or are you asking to sum (or other aggregate) 1 row (which isn't an aggregate, it's a select), then 2 rows, then 4?

Comment: That's going to be difficult. You'll need to apply some sort of windowing function to each row that can determine its *n*, and group on that. But without a sample of your data and desired result (not to mention what RDBMS you're using, since they have different capabilities in this regard) it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Comment: You will also need to define the **order** itself.

Answer (score 2):

The log base 2 of the row number will give you the grouping you want.

In sql server you can do this with

```
select floor(log((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by someColumn))) / log(2))
from yourTable
```

SqlServer 2012 has a log function that accepts a second parameter for the base of the log, but prior to that you need to convert to log base 2 from either log base 10 (log10 function) or natural log (log function) yourself.  I found the conversion formula [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm)